# Can we know the directory where the macro or functions are located in cmake

Tags: cmake

In CMAKE, it defines the following variables to indicate the directories of files:

```
CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR
CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR
```

They are useful when you process CMake scripts. However, none of them can tell you the directory where MACROs or functions are defined. Give the following example CMakeLists.txt to illustrate my question

```
project(Hello)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/my_macro.cmake)
test_macro()
```

Then for the my_macro.cmake, we have definitions for `test_macro()`:

```
macro(test_macro)
  message("hello")
  #?? Can we know the folder of this macro is located?
  #?? the macro definition file's location
endmacro()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there's an off-the-shelf variable for that, but you could easily make your own:

**my_macro.cmake**:

```
set(test_macro__internal_dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} CACHE INTERNAL "")

macro(test_macro)
  message(STATUS "Defined in: ${test_macro__internal_dir}")
endmacro()
```

The `set()` line will be processed when the file is included, and the value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` from that processing cached for future use inside the macro.

Comment: Great answer! One recommendation: you should take care that this cached variable has a unique name, or your scripts might interfere with each other

Answer (score 2):

With CMake 3.17 there is `CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR` that can be used in functions, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html
Unfortunately, there is no such thing for macros yet.