# cmake configure_file() path in cmake_modules_path

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to write modules to use CMake with a custom compiler, however I'm stuck in `CMakeDetermineCUSTOMCompiler.cmake`. I'd like the modules to work either installed inside of CMake's Modules directory or an external directoy specified by `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

To make it work installed in CMake's directory I can put:

```
configure_file(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeCUSTOMCompiler.cmake.in
```

but then it doesn't work with CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. Is there any where I can reference the location of the current module? Or search the locations specified in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH?

Comment: Looks like variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) is what you seek: it refers to the location of the currently processed file. Note, that for use such reference inside function or macro, you need firstly to [cache it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939360/can-we-know-the-directory-where-the-macro-or-functions-are-located-in-cmake/31940031#31940031).

Comment: I had thought it referred only to the current `CMakeLists.txt`, but you're right, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) is what you seek: it refers to the location of the currently processed file.

Note, that for use such reference inside function or macro, you need firstly to [cache it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939360/can-we-know-the-directory-where-the-macro-or-functions-are-located-in-cmake/31940031#31940031).